# Accessing not Non-QObject-based objects from Qt Script

Tags: qt, qtscript

Is there any nice and simple way to access non QObject-based classes, such as QXmlQuery, QDateTime etc. from Qt Script?

The only way I see is to wrap QXmlQuery in another class that inherits QObject and declare as slot every function which I need to access from Qt Script:

```
void MyXmlQuery::setQuery ( const QString & sourceCode, const QUrl & documentURI )
{
    realxmlquery_.setQuery(sourceCode, documentURI);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a interface class to do this job.

```
void MyXmlQuery::setQuery ( const QString & sourceCode, const QUrl & documentURI )
{
    this->realxmlquery_->setQuery(sourceCode, documentURI); //realxmlquery is a reference to the Non-qt class!
}
```